# Should I mention on my CV I'm happy to learn a native language of the country?

Tags: resume, recruitment

I'm looking for a job abroad (Netherlands) and I expect my English skills to be enough for a successful application into positions I'm looking for (Data Science/Software Engineering). I'm planning to learn language of the country I'm moving though, at least at a basic level (and if useful at the job, it would be additional motivation). Should I mention this at my CV? If yes, how?

Comment: *"I expect my English skills to be enough for a successful application into positions I'm looking for"* - if that's true, then why mention another language at all? And if the other language actually *is* important, then probably better to learn it first versus coming off as someone without the right skills.

Comment: I would expect it can result in some "bonus points", as it shows I plan to stay longer in the new country and potentially I could be promoted in the future into roles that requires knowledge of local language

Comment: Can you provide any context in terms of the foreign country, the nature of the job, etc.? That may help people give more relevant answers.

Comment: Updated. I asked general question, as I hoped it could be more useful for other people in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked,

> Should I mention this at my CV? If yes, how?

In a comment, you clarified your goal:

> I would expect it can result in some "bonus points", as it shows I plan to stay longer in the new country and potentially I could be promoted in the future into roles that requires knowledge of local language

It's always good to seek bonus points, but there needs to be some separation between bonus points versus showing you meet the actual job requirements - if something is required, ideally you could show it more strongly on your resume than just "I plan on learning this." And, if the thing isn't really required, or is unimportant enough that it's not directly relevant, then you need to ask yourself a few questions:

- Will including this make my resume too busy?
- Will it distract from more relevant content?
- Will it misdirect the interviewers' attention and cause potentially unwanted follow up questions?

If your resume isn't already on the verge of being too big, or too full of "bonus points" then it may be worth adding your intention, if you feel that it doesn't put you at any risk in terms of being a distraction or having any other negative result. Most resume formats have a section at the top where skills are listed, it would make sense to include languages there. If the country you're moving to is bi-lingual, and English is the primary language for your intended job, you would at least want to indicate you are fluent in English:

> Fluent in English

If you intend to learn a secondary language, you can certainly mention that, but it may be more powerful to at least take an intro course before you move, and then list that. It's **always** more powerful to show that you've already done something, versus that you really want to do something in the future:

> Beginner in Klingon

or,

> Conversational in Klingon

both look much better than,

> Intending to learn Klingon

Comment: Agree, "intending to learn ..." or "planning to learn" is not very helpful. "Enjoying learning ..." would be good, but be prepared to back it up.

Answer (score 2):

This should go in the cover letter not the CV

**Resume**: Your skills, work experience, education. Same for all jobs you apply. The resume is specific to you, not the job. Learning intent wouldn't go in here, since it's not a skill you have (yet)

**Cover Letter**: Why is this is job a good fit for you and why are you a good fit for this job. Overlay of the job requirements with your resume. Highly specific and tailored to this job and your personal career. That's a great place to mention this. Something like "I'm really excited about this opportunity since I want to immerse myself in Dutch culture and the language"